# iOS RSA Public Key send to server

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, rsa, public-key

I have generated RSA Key pairs using SecKeyGeneratePair method and using those keys I can able to do the encryption/decryption, digital signature and do the verification in iOS application.

Now the challenge is I need to send the public key(SecKeyRef) to Java server as a base64string format, in java I have to reconstruct the public key using iOS string(base64).

I have converted SecKeyRef to NSData to base64string(always getting same string) while transferring it to server.  Using base64string I am not able to reconstruct the public key in Java. I have mentioned below the used code for generating RSA Public and Private keys.

```
static const UInt8 publicKeyIdentifier[] =  "com.apple.sample.publickey\0";
static const UInt8 privateKeyIdentifier[]= "com.apple.sample.privatekey\0";


- (void)generateKeyPairPlease{

OSStatus status = noErr;
publicKeyBits=nil;
NSMutableDictionary *privateKeyAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *publicKeyAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *keyPairAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

publicTag = [NSData dataWithBytes:publicKeyIdentifier length:strlen((const char *)publicKeyIdentifier)];

privateTag = [NSData dataWithBytes:privateKeyIdentifier length:strlen((const char *)privateKeyIdentifier)];
publicKey = NULL;
privateKey = NULL;


[keyPairAttr setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];

[keyPairAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1024] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits];

[privateKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrIsPermanent];

[privateKeyAttr setObject:privateTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];

[publicKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrIsPermanent];

[publicKeyAttr setObject:publicTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];

[keyPairAttr setObject:privateKeyAttr forKey:(__bridge id)kSecPrivateKeyAttrs];

[keyPairAttr setObject:publicKeyAttr forKey:(__bridge id)kSecPublicKeyAttrs];

status = SecKeyGeneratePair((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keyPairAttr,&publicKey, &privateKey);

}


- (NSData *)getPublicKeyBits {
OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;

CFDataRef keyBits;

NSMutableDictionary * queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// Set the public key query dictionary.
[queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
[queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
[queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
[queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];

// Get the key bits.
sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, (CFTypeRef *)&keyBits);
publicKeyBits =(__bridge_transfer NSData*)keyBits; 

if (sanityCheck != noErr)
{
publicKeyBits = nil;
}

NSLog(@"Bits are %@",publicKeyBits);

return publicKeyBits;//every time I am getting same data here
}
```

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850306/ios-seckeyref-public-key-send-it-to-server and the answer is there.